# seaborn regplot non - continuous fitting problems

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, seaborn

When I using regplot to plot and fit multiple groups of data, the regplot function cannot fit after many iterations, the results are shown below. However, when I choose only one group of data from the above data, the fit and plot work. Can any tell me why is that and how to fix that?

PS. I have tryed lmplot(), same results.

Code:

```
def generate_regplot(df, x, y, col, hue):
    col_order = np.unique(df[col])
    col_order = list(col_order)     
    col_order.sort(reverse=True)
    g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=col, col_order=col_order, hue=hue, height=8, aspect=.2)
    g = g.map (sns.regplot, x, y, order=5, scatter_kws=({'s': 0.1}))

def generate_regplot(df, x, y, col, hue):
    col_order = np.unique(df[col])
    col_order = list(col_order)      
    col_order.sort(reverse=True)
    g = sns.FacetGrid(df, col=col, col_order=col_order, hue=hue, height=8, aspect=.2)
    g = g.map (sns.regplot, x, y, order=5, scatter_kws=({'s': 0.1}))
    g = generate_regplot(df=df, x='Radius', y='Plot_CD', col='Wordline', hue=hue)
    g.axes[0][0].set_ylabel("CD [nm]", fontsize=18)

    for ax in g.axes.flat:
        ax.set_xlim(plt_rad_min, plt_rad_max)
        ax.set_ylim(plt_y_min, plt_y_max)
        ax.set_xlabel("Radius", fontsize=18)
        ax.set_xticks(x_tick_locs_rad)
        ax.set_xticklabels(x_tick_locs_rad, rotation=90)
        ax = draw_spec_lines(ax, upper_spec_lim, lower_spec_lim, punch_spec_lim)
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
    plt.legend(title=legend_title_parse(hue), markerscale = 20, fontsize='large', title_fontsize='16', loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.45, 1))
    plt.draw()

    return g
```

[the plot for single group of data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4SIX.png)

[the plot for multiple group of data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmMLl.png)